# View is not getting stretched to edges of phone on landscape orientation? How to add constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios

How to add constraints programmatically for views which should be placed next to each other on scroll view?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:10];

[self.scrollView addConstraint:constraint];
```

constraints are basically a equation iOS will try to satisfy at runtime.

General form is:

item1.attribute = multiplier * (item2.attribute) + constant

In the code above:

view2.left = 1 * (view1.right) + 10

So view2's left will be at 10pt space from view1's right.